# Xdebug with Visual Studio Code ignores some breakpoints

Tags: php, laravel, visual-studio-code, xdebug

I am using Visual Studio Code with the PHP Debug extension to debug a Laravel project. But some breakpoints are ignored and I cannot figure out why. I insist on the fact that not all breakpoints are ignored. For instance all breakpoints at method declarations are ignored but those at variable declarations are hit.

The Xdebug part of my `php.ini`:

```
xdebug.profiler_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
```

This is my `launch.json`:

```js
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for XDebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9001,
            "log": true
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch currently open script",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "port": 9000
        }
    ]
}
```

What I tried:

- Changing the default port 9000 to 9001
- Uninstalling and reinstalling the PHP debug extension (you never know)

Example: the "•" indicates a line breakpoint. All the breakpoints in the code sample below are ignored.

```php
 public function testCreateWhenAllParametersAreCorrectlySpecifiedReturnsCompany()
 {
•    $attributes = [
         'business_name' => 'DANONE'
     ];

     $address = factory(Address::class)->create();

     $company = Company::create($attributes, $address);

     $this->assertInstanceOf(Company::class, $company);

     $this->assertDatabaseHas('companies', [
•        'address_id' => $address->id,
         'business_name' => 'DANONE'
     ]);
 }
```

How to get Xdebug with Visual Studio Code hitting all breakpoints or is this normal behaviour? Thank you in advance for your help.

**Update #1 (08/07/2019)**

The Zend extension path is specified in my `php.ini` like below.

```
zend_extension = "/usr/local/Cellar/php@7.2/7.2.18/pecl/20170718/xdebug.so"
```

And I tried to add `php.validate.executablePath` in my `settings.json`.

**Update #2 (08/08/2019)**

According to the comments and the answers at the time of this update, Xdebug ignoring some lines is the normal behavior. My questions then are why are some lines ignored? What kinds of lines are ignored? Is there an official list?

Comment: Where those non-working breakpoints are? What kind of lines they are? A screenshot is welcome. Try placing `xdebug_break();` in your code and see if it will trigger it. P.S. I suggest placing breakpoints on actual lines of code and they better be single liners / simple instructions. Due to the way how PHP generated byte code, some breakpoints have different line that you would expect (e.g. multi line array declaration -- it would be somewhere in the middle). P.P.S. Maybe VSC does not support "method breakpoints" (when it's placed on the function declaration line).

Comment: P.S. If one breakpoint works and another does not, then changing ports will do nothing. Changing port may be needed only if you do not receive any connection from Xdebug at all (e.g. some another service is running on that port, e.g. php-fpm is a typical case). In any case: enable & collect and then check Xdebug log -- it will tell where it tries to connect (and if it's successfull or not), on what lines breakpoints are set etc.

Comment: I supposed changing the port would not fix the problem. I mentioned it anyway so people know I did everything in my power.

Comment: So it would be neither a problem of configuration nor a bug but just the way things are. I indeed noticed that breakpoints in the middle of a multiple lines array were ignored.

Comment: Please add the code and also on which particular lines the breakpoints don't work?

Comment: Can you try another IDE e.g. NetBeans to check if the IDE is the bad man

Comment: @TarunLalwani I added a test method where breakpoints don't work. Let me know if it is not enough or if you need more details.

Comment: @Black do you think that trying with Sublime Text and the Xdebug Client plugin would do the job?

Comment: As I have stated in my very first comment -- you are placing breakpoints on the wrong lines. Actual breakpoint for a multi-line array declaration will be somewhere in the middle: just put breakpoint on a single liner before and try to step through the code (Step Over) -- you will see where it stops and what lines are omitted. See these Xdebug tickets: https://bugs.xdebug.org/view.php?id=869, https://bugs.xdebug.org/view.php?id=618 and what Xdebug author says there (unable to fix)  **P.S.** For PhpStorm users: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-4721 and related.

Comment: **P.P.S.** Xdebug **2.8** should have "breakpoint validation" mechanism in place: it will give instant feedback if breakpoint set in that line will be hit or not. Obviously, debug client (IDE/editor) would need to be aware of that/support this as well.

Comment: @LazyOne How am supposed to know there are wrong lines? I tested Xdebug a lot and now I have an idea of the kinds of lines that are ignored. But are they rules? A documentation? Or am I juste supposed to guess? I will reword my question.

Comment: @louisfischer 1) Check Xdebug tickets from my 2nd last comment -- Xdebug author commented there why he cannot do anything about it. 2) You cannot know that in advance until you experience this yourself (at very least I do not know such list, even though it's mentioned here and there briefly). That is why 2.8 will have that "test" functionality that will tell "breakpoint is good": *"The 2.8 series primarily adds support for PHP 7.4, but also improves Xdebug's breakpoint functionality by adding support for the 'resolved_breakpoint' flag."* http://bugs.xdebug.org/bug_view_page.php?bug_id=00001388

Comment: @louisfischer More info on why (in addition to explanation from https://bugs.xdebug.org/view.php?id=618): https://derickrethans.nl/breakpoints.html

Comment: @LazyOne do you think you could combine into an answer all the stuff you wrote and resources you gave in the comments? That way this bounty won't go away...

Comment: @louisfischer I do not think that I will be able to create a really comprehensive answer here (that would cover all angels). You may accept **rkeet**'s answer -- it does not have the links but it describes the overall picture IMO. Or you can make your own answer with your findings and actual experience on what works for your code/thoughts.

Comment: @LazyOne Hope you don't mind, included some of these comments (credits in there ;) ) in an edit to my answer. You might like to know: 2.8.0 (with this fix you mentioned) is scheduled for release 2019-09-30.

Comment: @rkeet Please use whatever URLs you need (the more the better): it will make a better answer without a need for going through the comments, e.g. explanation with why such breakpoints are not getting hit/links to tickets where such explanation is present etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Running it in PhpStorm, but as Xdebug runs on PHP, the behavior is the same.

Xdebug stops when stuff is "done", on the lines that things are "done". This can be function calls, variable assignments, data transformations, etc. All these have in common that they must be explicit. Implicit assignments are ignored.

Xdebug does not pause execution for breakpoints placed "in" an action. Which is why the first breakpoint in your code *will not* work, and the second will.

Explicit & implicit example:

```
$attributes = [                   // this is implicitly an array, no pausing execution
    'business_name' => 'DANONE'   // this is explicitly assigned a string, execution paused
];
```

With some screenshots (code is from Symfony 4 `public/index.php`, with some obvious additions - blue background is paused execution "current line"):

[image: example 1]

Clearly executing functions inside an `if()` statement - it pauses

[image: example 2]

As we can see, breakpoints on all 3 lines of this array. However, the only one it pauses on is the assignment of the key/value pair. This is explicitly done, the array itself is implicitly declared.

[image: example 3]

Here we explicitly declare `$testArray` to be an array. So: it pauses.

[image: example 4]

This is to be complete, could've added it above. Implicit setting of type array, but explicit assigning of key/value.

---

So: yes.

If you had placed your breakpoints slightly different, they would've paused the execution. Not pausing on the implicit ones is normal behavior.

---

To be complete:

On local Apache installation I've got the following config:

```
[XDEBUG]
zend_extension = C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.7.1-7.3-vc15-x86_64.dll

xdebug.remote_mode = req
xdebug.remote_connect_back = 1
xdebug.default_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.remote_handler = dbgp
xdebug.max_nesting_level = 200;
```

But I normally run this in Docker. In the `docker-compose` PHP image:

```
environment:
  PHP_XDEBUG_ENABLED: ${XDEBUG_ENABLED:-0}
  PHP_IDE_CONFIG: ${PHP_IDE_CONFIG:-serverName=ProjectName}
  XDEBUG_CONFIG: >
    idekey=PHPSTORM 
    remote_host=${XDEBUG_REMOTE_HOST_IP:-host.docker.internal}
    remote_port=${XDEBUG_REMOTE_PORT:-9000}
    remote_enable=1
```

- (to enable xdebug, set `XDEBUG_ENABLED` environment config to `1` in application when starting using `docker-compose up`)
- (replace "ProjectName" with the name of the project, use that name in your "servers" config in PhpStorm settings for Xdebug)

and in the `Dockerfile`

```
pecl install xdebug-2.7.2 redis && \
docker-php-ext-enable xdebug redis && \
```

- (make sure to replace `xdebug-2.7.2` with a version you want / is compatible with your PHP version, [check that here](https://xdebug.org/wizard.php))

---

Edit: additional based on comments on OP's question.

There's plenty of bug reports (see those comments, credit to [LazyOne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/783119/lazyone) for finding them).

The last URL he provided is interesting as it's about the upcoming V2.8.0 (currently in 2.8.0beta1, not general release), about which he comments in [this ticket](https://bugs.xdebug.org/bug_view_page.php?bug_id=00001388) about Xdebug not pausing execution on the implicit assignments:

> I've just merged this into the master branch, which will become part of 2.8.0. I will release 2.7.2 soon (this week, today?!), and then probably next week a 2.8alpha1 release so that people can try this out.

(quote from 2019-05-06 12:49 by Derick, writer of Xdebug)

You can have a look at the [changelog page](https://bugs.xdebug.org/changelog_page.php) or the [roadmap](https://bugs.xdebug.org/roadmap_page.php) for Xdebug.

The roadmap shows all of the features / fixes which will be included.

For 2.8.0 it shows that support for IDE's will be added for IDE's to show whether or not a breakpoint can be resolved. It's current release date is set for 2019-09-30.

Released

Answer (score 3):

It's not available to break by defined array in vscode
my suggestion is to get some if or other code, like this:

```
 public function testCreateWhenAllParametersAreCorrectlySpecifiedReturnsCompany()
 {
•   $debug = 'true';
    $attributes = [
         'business_name' => 'DANONE'
     ];

     $address = factory(Address::class)->create();

     $company = Company::create($attributes, $address);

•    $this->assertInstanceOf(Company::class, $company);

     $this->assertDatabaseHas('companies', [
         'address_id' => $address->id,
         'business_name' => 'DANONE'
     ]);
 }
```

and continue with press `f10` button

Comment: I could add some logging too. Isn't the point of Xdebug coupled with an IDE to avoid debug code?

Comment: You saw that reaction? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57323475/xdebug-with-visual-studio-code-ignores-some-breakpoints/57376569#comment101244760_57323475

Answer (score 1):

I too faced this problem, with `laravel`, im posting what steps I did to fix this problem
I'm using laragon   for PHP

added a new php version,
also updated composers PHP path(don't know if this step is requiered, but I did it and pointed to latest PHP version)

downloaded xdebg.dll and placed in the folder

updated configuration in `php.ini`

```
[xdebug]    
 zend_extension = D:\lrgn\bin\php\php-7.2.7\ext\php_xdebug-2.6.1-7.2-vc15-nts-x86_64.dll
 xdebug.remote_autostart=1
 xdebug.remote_enable=1
 xdebug.remote_connect_back = 1
 ;xdebug.remote_log= D:\lrgn\bin\log\xdebug.log
```

i dont have xdebug.remote_port = 9000

in launch.json

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for XDebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9000
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch currently open script",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "port": 9000
        }
    ]
}
```

on vscode

In   Preferences --> Settings (`ctrl`+`,`)

Add/update:
 `php.validate.executablePath: "D:\lrgn\bin\php\php-7.2.7\php.exe"` (mine was here)

**Restarted server**(laragon)
stoped laravel
did a composer update on project(not sure is this stage require)
started  laravel project again

on browser open laravel project

on vscode set some brakepoints even in methods

in debug section -> Listen for XDebug

on browser reloaded the page

yes, it's a direct hit

Comment: "laragon <3" does `<3` mean heart or smaller than 3?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Are you saying using Laragon fixed your problem? The Zend extension path is specified in my `php.ini` and I tried to add `php.validate.executablePath` in my `settings.json`. Breakpoints are still ignored.

Answer (score -2):

I faced the same error.

I fixed that just download old version of xdebug.

You can download it from this [link](https://xdebug.org/download/historical).